# How can I avoid seeing this NULL values in BigQuery (SQL)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, null

I have a problem when querying a database that has information about the New York Citibike system, what I want is to know which ones are the ten most used routes in the New York Citibike system, the average trip duration, and route ( from the start station to end station)

[This is how the table looks like, part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGvfm.png)

[This is part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3YsC.png)

[And the final part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLmE6.png)

So, the query that I am doing is this one:

```
    SELECT 
    usertype,
    CONCAT(start_station_name, ' to ', end_station_name) AS route,
    COUNT(*) AS num_trips,
    ROUND(AVG(CAST(tripduration as int64)/60),2) AS duration_minutes,

    FROM 
    bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips

    GROUP BY 
    start_station_name,
    end_station_name,
    usertype

    ORDER BY 
    num_trips DESC

    LIMIT 10
```

The problem is that it returns what I want but also returns the row on the top that I dont need. Did I make a mistake or does it simply meant that there is blank information in the dataset?

[I am just showing the first 4 rows, but in the video that is explaining this to me in the certificate, it does not appear the black (the first one) row...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xE0S9.png)

[This is how looks in the video:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7jvN.png)

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

> (did I make a mistake or it is just that there is blank information in the dataset?)

As someone who is learning data/sql, be sure to always investigate your data!

The following query shows that station names are empty for a blank `usertype`.

```
select distinct start_station_name, end_station_name
from bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips
where usertype = ''
```

You will likely want to add a `where usertype <> ''` filter to your query if you want to suppress those records.

Comment: Bro (I don´t know if you are a "bro", but it is just an idiom), thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed. What happened is that my instructor in the video acted like the dataset was clean, so I assumed that, but it turns out that the dataset was updated after my instructor used the dataset, so my dataset was different from hers. Thank you so much for your help, now I know how to ignore NULLs values when I want to, ty.